# Expand/ Collapse Icons after filtering an ag-grid with grouped data still visible

Tags: ag-grid

I have an ag-grid with grouped tree data. Everything is working fine but when I filter the ag-grid with an external filter and all children of one group are filtered out, the expand/ collapse button is still visible, like for example:

[image]

One can see a node with two children.

[image]

After filtering for the text "node with", the child nodes are "removed" but I can still see the icon as if there were children.

[image]

I can now even expand/ collapse as long as I want but only the icon changes.

What is the best way to get rid of these icons? Unfortunately I cannot find a property like HideIconIfNoChildren which I can set to true so the only thing I can think of is to use somehow the getRowClass callback but this seems very dirty to me.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Another example that shows the issue:
[image]

The [demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/#example-file-browser) from ag-grid can be found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/#example-file-browser)!

The expand/collapse icon is still visible although the folder *xls* doesn't have any visible children anymore! How to remove the icon in these cases?

Comment: share your sample pls

Comment: Look at [group cell renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#grid-renderer-aggroupcellrenderer). It will give you control over how group cell will look and behave

Comment: Hi @un.spike, there is a nice sample in the ag-grid documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/#example-file-browser If you filter here, you get the same result as shown in the pictures above - you can still toggle the expand/ collapse icon but as the children are all filtered away, nothing changes but the icon.

Comment: @mashi, I'll have a look at the group cell renderer but I guess that this would come very close to the dirty solution mentioned above! ;) I'll post an update if I have news!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way to handle it (and I suspect if you dig deep enough you will find a way to override in the grid itself via one of the Renderers). But you 'could'  override the icons so they do not appear in the  app.

i.e add the following to the application style.css (needed as you cant override the grid style in class) - note only hitting the expanded to show proof of concept

```
.ag-icon-expanded  {
    background-color: white !important;
    color: white !important ;
    background-image: none !important;
    }
```

and then in your group-row-inner-renderer handle the icon yourself by making it appear and disappear dependant on the params passed in. You can find the grid icon in the style though you dont have to use the grids if overriding globally.

```
url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTYiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTQgN2w0IDQgNC00IiBzdHJva2U9IiM3RjhDOEQiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiLz48L3N2Zz4=);
```

When i filter out grids if their are no children then the row disappears so allowing you want a visible row with no children the above should work with some tweaking...

You might want to avoid the !important as I have not ascertained whether needed or not..

Just for completeness the following is an override of the header component (different to what you will be doing) but shows what the override class does with params, hiding/showing different icons dependant on params and manually handling some of the header cell stuff

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-loading-overlay',
    template: `
        <div (mouseenter)="onHover(true)" (mouseleave)="onHover(false)">
            <div *ngIf="params.enableMenu && showMenu == true" #menuButton class="customHeaderMenuButton" (click)="onMenuClicked($event)"><i class="fa {{params.menuIcon}}"></i></div> 

            <div *ngIf="!params.enableMenu && params.materialIcon != null" #menuButton class="customHeaderMenuButton"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:14px;">{{params.materialIcon}}</i></div> 
            <div *ngIf="!params.enableMenu && params.imageIconLink != null" #menuButton class="customHeaderMenuButton"><img src='{{params.imageIconLink}}' style='height:15px; margin-left: -2px; filter: grayscale(100%);'/></div> 
            <div *ngIf="!params.enableMenu && params.glyphIcon != null" #menuButton class="customHeaderMenuButton" ><span class='{{params.glyphIcon}}' style='color:black; font-size:14px; margin-left: -7px; float: left; width: "25px";' aria-hidden='true'></span></div> 
            <div *ngIf="params.enableMenu && showMenu == true && params.enableSorting == true" (click)="onSortRequested('asc', $event)" [ngClass]="ascSort" class="customSortDownLabel"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i></div> 
            <div *ngIf="params.enableMenu && showMenu == true && params.enableSorting == true" (click)="onSortRequested('desc', $event)" [ngClass]="descSort" class="customSortUpLabel"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i></div> 
            <div *ngIf="params.enableMenu && showMenu == true && params.enableSorting == true" (click)="onSortRequested('', $event)" [ngClass]="noSort" class="customSortRemoveLabel"><i class="fa fa-times" style="padding-right: 5px"></i></div>
            <div class="customHeaderLabel" *ngIf="params.displayName">{{params.displayName}}</div> 

        </div>
    `,
    styles: [
        `
        .customHeaderMenuButton {
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 4px;
            float: left;
        }

        .customHeaderLabel {
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-top: 3px;
            text-overflow: clip;
            overflow: visible;
            white-space: normal;
        }

        .customSortDownLabel {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        .customSortUpLabel {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-top: 4px;
        }

        .customSortRemoveLabel {
            float: left;
            font-size: 11px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }

        .active {
            color: cornflowerblue;
        }
    `
    ]
})
export class CustomHeader {
    public params: any;

    private ascSort: string;
    private descSort: string;
    private noSort: string;
    public showMenu: boolean = false;
    public blockSorting: boolean = false;

    @ViewChild('menuButton', {read: ElementRef}) public menuButton;

    agInit(params): void {
        this.params = params;

        if(this.params.displayName == null )
        {
            this.params.displayName = "";
        }

        params.column.addEventListener('sortChanged', this.onSortChanged.bind(this));
        this.onSortChanged();
    }

    onMenuClicked() {
        if(this.params.enableMenu == true){
            this.params.showColumnMenu(this.menuButton.nativeElement);
        }

    };

    onHover(set: boolean){
        if(set){
            this.showMenu = true;
        }
        else{
            this.showMenu = false;
        }

    }

    onSortChanged() {
        this.ascSort = this.descSort = this.noSort = 'inactive';
        if (this.params.column.isSortAscending()) {
            this.ascSort = 'active';
        } else if (this.params.column.isSortDescending()) {
            this.descSort = 'active';
        } else {
            this.noSort = 'active';
        }
    }

    onSortRequested(order, event) {
        this.params.setSort(order, event.shiftKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on "and then in your group-row-inner-renderer handle the icon yourself by making it appear and disappear dependant on the params passed in." - because that is precisely the part I don't know how to do! :)

Comment: K, if you go to the ag-grid site and look at their example for Full Width Grid Rows (half way down the page approx) https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#group-cell-rendering

Comment: To continue the above. The easy way is to open it in plunker (the example provides a link) there you can see the class you need to deal with, make the changes and see the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can override filter (cuz by default for grouped columns `agSetColumnFilter` is used)

```
this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
  headerName: "Files",
  width: 250,
  filter: "agTextColumnFilter", <---
  cellRendererParams: {
    checkbox: true,
    suppressCount: true,
    innerRenderer: "fileCellRenderer"
  }
};
```

and it will work as expected

[image]

Comment: un.spike, thank you for your reply but I don't understand. The question is about a node that has children but all of these children are filtered away. In your example, if you remove xyz.txt, the expand/ collapse icon is still visible although no visible children are left. I'll post another image in my questin to make things clearer. But thank you anyway!

Comment: No, I got it, you wanna to hide empty `folders` icon, but currently `fileRenderer` doesn't handle it, so might be you need to create own `renderer` and handle visibility internally.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems so and even more unfortunate is, that the innerRenderer is not enough. One would have to overwrite the group cell renderer. But as I want to keep ALL other functionality, one would have to copy the ag-grid implementation, make changes and wait for bad things to happen (for example: ag-grid changes their code). I still can't believe that ag-grid doesn't provide a better way of doing simple things like that. I'll keep looking for a better solution! :)

Comment: check [this one](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/#example-highlighting-drag-tree-data) if you will drag from one to another (empty parent-icon would be removed)
So, as I said before, try to use `agTextColumnFilter` instead of `agSetColumnFilter ` or [`quickFilter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/#example-org-hierarchy)
I suppose it would be possible to handle filtering only by file names (not by all path)

Comment: That is a nice example. Looked promising but unfortunately, they are changing the actual data, the filePath! And the filePath is responsible for maintaining the hierarchy. That means that this node, after moving it, actually and really doesn't have any children left, so ag-grid removes the icon automatically. But in my case there are still children! They are just not visible!

Comment: Yep, tried to check deep src and didn't get a way to remove `group` icon (only can add lol)